# SDWebImage Complete closure is called 4 times per image

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) with [progress](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage).

I use the following code in an `init()`` constructor:

```
if let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: previewCard.getImageUrls().getWithInt(0) as! String) {
  self.imageView?.setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: MGImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), options: SDWebImageOptions.RefreshCached, completed: { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, type:SDImageCacheType, loadUrl:NSURL!) -> Void in

    println("-------------- done")
    }, usingActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)

}
```

The console output is:

```
 println("-------------- done")
 println("-------------- done")
 println("-------------- done")
 println("-------------- done")
```

**Why is the complete closure called four times? How can I prevent that it is called four times?**

Edit: I verified that the init() method is called only once. Wherever I call the `setImageWithUrl` method the complete closure is called at least twice.

Comment: That is peculiar. Are you creating only one of the object? (Isn't the `init
()` method called multiple times)?

Comment: There's not enough context here for us to guess where you're calling this code 4 times.

Comment: I verified that the init() method is called only once.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're specifying "RefreshCached". Check out the documentation [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.5.4/Constants/SDWebImageOptions.html). Specifically this line under SDWebImageRefreshCached:

> the completion block is called once with the cached image and again
>   with the final image

So you should always get at least two callbacks. Since you're getting four callbacks rather than two, I would guess you're either getting errors (so check if the "error" param tells you anything useful), or you're refreshing large images and getting some progress updates along the way. Regardless, the last callback will be the one that contains the refreshed image you want.